# Prolog ERROR: Undefined procedure: transpose/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Tags: prolog

I have just started with Prolog for one of my classes so it's quite basic. I just had a doubt that does Prolog not have any inbuilt functions that can be used directly or should we always be writing a set of facts and rules first and then use them? I was trying to run this function:

**?-transpose([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],Ts).**

Which gave me this error:

**ERROR: Undefined procedure: transpose/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)**

So, basically, my question is, do I need to write how the transpose would work? I thought it was an inbuilt function ready to use.

P.S.: I am using: SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.6.0-rc1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it has quite a few built-in predicates (listed in http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=builtin) but `transpose` is not one of them. If it's "for one of my classes so it's quite basic", most likely you are expected to write `transpose` yourself, especially if it's your first Prolog class.

There *is* one in `clfpd` library, see [How to use predicate transpose in SWI-Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477057/how-to-use-predicate-transpose-in-swi-prolog).